# java.io.IOException: PHP FastCGI server not running

Tags: php, tomcat7, php-java-bridge

I configured piwik php code to my apache tomcat server using java-bridge and php-servlet api,

It is working fine for the local environment with window, but while same thing done on test environment, There also working fine but after some time it is falling and giving following exception :

If anyone having the same experience please help me to get it out.

```
type Exception report

message PHP FastCGI server not running. Please see server log for details. Or start a PHP FastCGI server using the command:

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

java.io.IOException: PHP FastCGI server not running. Please see server log for details. Or start a PHP FastCGI server using the command:
cd /liferay-portal-6.2-ee-sp7/tomcat-7.0.42/webapps/piwik/WEB-INF/cgi/amd64-linux
REDIRECT_STATUS=200 X_JAVABRIDGE_OVERRIDE_HOSTS="/" PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN="5" PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS="5000" /usr/bin/php-cgi -b 127.0.0.1:9668


    php.java.servlet.fastcgi.FastCGIServlet.handle(FastCGIServlet.java:489)
    php.java.servlet.fastcgi.FastCGIServlet.doGet(FastCGIServlet.java:521)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    php.java.servlet.PhpCGIFilter.doFilter(PhpCGIFilter.java:126)
root cause

java.io.IOException: PHP FastCGI server failed: 
    php.java.servlet.fastcgi.FastCGIServlet.execute(FastCGIServlet.java:439)
    php.java.servlet.fastcgi.FastCGIServlet.handle(FastCGIServlet.java:481)
    php.java.servlet.fastcgi.FastCGIServlet.doGet(FastCGIServlet.java:521)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    php.java.servlet.PhpCGIFilter.doFilter(PhpCGIFilter.java:126)
root cause

php.java.bridge.http.FCGIConnectException: Could not connect to server
    php.java.bridge.http.SocketChannelFactory.doConnect(SocketChannelFactory.java:77)
    php.java.bridge.http.SocketChannelFactory.connect(SocketChannelFactory.java:88)
    php.java.servlet.ContextLoaderListener$1.connect(ContextLoaderListener.java:533)
    php.java.bridge.http.FCGIConnectionPool$Connection.reopen(FCGIConnectionPool.java:101)
    php.java.bridge.http.FCGIConnectionPool.openConnection(FCGIConnectionPool.java:224)
    php.java.servlet.fastcgi.FastCGIServlet.parseBody(FastCGIServlet.java:312)
    php.java.servlet.fastcgi.FastCGIServlet.execute(FastCGIServlet.java:433)
    php.java.servlet.fastcgi.FastCGIServlet.handle(FastCGIServlet.java:481)
    php.java.servlet.fastcgi.FastCGIServlet.doGet(FastCGIServlet.java:521)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    php.java.servlet.PhpCGIFilter.doFilter(PhpCGIFilter.java:126)
root cause

java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
    java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:241)
    php.java.bridge.http.SocketChannelFactory.doConnect(SocketChannelFactory.java:75)
    php.java.bridge.http.SocketChannelFactory.connect(SocketChannelFactory.java:88)
    php.java.servlet.ContextLoaderListener$1.connect(ContextLoaderListener.java:533)
    php.java.bridge.http.FCGIConnectionPool$Connection.reopen(FCGIConnectionPool.java:101)
    php.java.bridge.http.FCGIConnectionPool.openConnection(FCGIConnectionPool.java:224)
    php.java.servlet.fastcgi.FastCGIServlet.parseBody(FastCGIServlet.java:312)
    php.java.servlet.fastcgi.FastCGIServlet.execute(FastCGIServlet.java:433)
    php.java.servlet.fastcgi.FastCGIServlet.handle(FastCGIServlet.java:481)
    php.java.servlet.fastcgi.FastCGIServlet.doGet(FastCGIServlet.java:521)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    php.java.servlet.PhpCGIFilter.doFilter(PhpCGIFilter.java:126)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.42 logs.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.42
```

Thanks!
Surendra

Comment: What does the log of the PHP FastCGI server says?

Comment: I am not aware much about PHP, I just download java-bridge.jar and configure the piwik code on tomcat. after that I got this error. This error I am getting after some time not instantly.

Comment: This error is happening on that PHP Fast CGI is running most probably. You should search for it to analyze the log files.

Comment: means PHP Fast CGI is running separately on the server?

Comment: Yes, probably it is.

Comment: but I don't have any idea to check the log for PHP Fast CGI anyway thanks Jarge, I forwarded this task to admin guys might be they have idea to support it.